# json не могу вывести циклом

Tags: php, json

Получаю `JSON`  из файла такого вида:

```
{"dayOfWeek":[
    "Среда",
    "Четверг",
    "Пятница",
    "Суббота",
    "Воскресенье",
    "Понедельник"
],
"expirationTimeUtc":[
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515
]}
```

---

```
$js = json_decode($json); 
foreach($js as $k) {
    echo $k->dayOfWeek;
}
```

Comment: А что выводит то?

Comment: Все-таки новички очень сильно путаются в массивах. Двухуровневая вложенность уже ставит их в тупик. Хотя казалось бы, что сложного обратиться к элементу первого уровня и вывести в цикле содержащийся в нем массив

Comment: не получается пройти по массиву и вывести допустим dayOfWeek выдает ошибку пробую так for ($i = 0; $i < $js; $i++) {
 echo $js->dayOfWeek[$i]; } выдает название первого дня и далее ошибка Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Comment: `$i < $js` и что-по-твоему это означает? Если 5 рублей меньше чем после дождичка в четверг? что с чем ты тут сравниваешь?

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$json = '{"dayOfWeek":[
    "Среда",
    "Четверг",
    "Пятница",
    "Суббота",
    "Воскресенье",
    "Понедельник"
],
"expirationTimeUtc":[
        1585722515,
        1585722515,
        1585722515,
        1585722515,
        1585722515,
        1585722515
    ]}';
$js = json_decode($json);
print_r($js);
foreach($js as $k=>$val) {
    if($k == 'dayOfWeek') {
        foreach ($val as $kk) {
            echo $kk;
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем здесь первый цикл? Чтобы этот несчастный еще больше запутался?

Comment: Серьезно - надо итерироваться по объекту чтобы найти проперть?

Comment: @Ипатьев Мне Вас искренне жалко.

Comment: А мне жалко всех посетителей этого сайта, которые потом читают вот такие вот ответы

Comment: @u_mulder Потому что после преобразования `foreach($js as $k) {` `$k` будет являться массивом. Хотя откуда Вам это знать...

Comment: @Ипатьев Вы ограниченный специалист. Я наблюдал Ваши работы. И Вот из-за Ваших ответов мне искренне Вас жаль. Вы даже не способны написать более-менее нормальный ответ.

Comment: он тебе про $js говорит, а не про $k. расскажи ещё про "ограниченность", ага

Comment: `foreach ($js->dayOfWeek as $kk)`, жалельщик.

Comment: @u_mulder Ахахаха ))) Вас не смущает, что `$js->dayOfWeek` Тоже сам по себе является массивом? )))) В общем понятно всё с вами. Вы можете вон друг с другом кубики обсуждать. Это Вам под силу.

Comment: Это вы мне предложили для каждого значения отдельный массив перебирать в json?

Comment: Да, `$js->dayOfWeek` __массив__ и достаточно __одного__ форыча чтобы по этой проперти итерироваться. Тут же зачем-то еще второй форыч, чтобы эту проперть найти, когда ее можно сразу получить как `$js->dayOfWeek`.

Comment: @u_mulder а если с остальными массивами надо тоже что-то делать?

Comment: вот я об этом и говорю

Comment: @MishaTp тебе предложили кривой, но рабочий вариант того что ты пытался накалякать сам. Никаких других задач в твоем вопросе написано **не было**

Comment: Я не знаю что там делать с остальными массивами, это не указано в вопросе. В любом случае добраться до нужной проперти\ключа очевидней через `->prop` \ `[key]`, а не через цикл с проверкой ключа.

Comment: @MishaTp После `foreach($js as $k) {` Вы получаете 2 массива - `dayOfWeek` и `expirationTimeUtc`. Для того, чтобы обработать все данные `json` в одном массиве, Вы можете использовать `foreach($js as $k=>$val) {`, где `$k` является ключём - `dayOfWeek` или `expirationTimeUtc`, а `$val` соответсвующими массивами. Не слушайте никого. Ребята просто не разбираются.

Comment: спасибо, разберусь далее сам

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{"dayOfWeek":[
    "Среда",
    "Четверг",
    "Пятница",
    "Суббота",
    "Воскресенье",
    "Понедельник"
],
"expirationTimeUtc":[
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515,
    1585722515
]}';

$js = json_decode($json); 
foreach($js->dayOfWeek as $k) {
    echo $k, PHP_EOL;
}
```

О чудо!!! Выводит то что нужно:

> Среда Четверг Пятница Суббота Воскресенье Понедельник

Ниже ещё один вариант

```
$js = json_decode($json, true); 
foreach($js['dayOfWeek'] as $k) {
    echo $k, PHP_EOL;
}
```